# grand total comes at each line, I will like to get it only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I will like to summarize the total of my billing.  I will like to get only one grand total.
Now I got it for each row in the db.

Actually the output comes like this.

```
 Stats

    Nombre de factures: 2

   Grand total des factures

   71.97
   71.97    <=== the total is coming twice.  I will like to get only one grand total
```

Stats.cshtml

```
 @model IEnumerable<Tp1WebStore3.Models.Facture>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Stats";
 }

 <h2>Stats</h2>

 <p>
     Nombre de factures: @Model.Count()  
 </p>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>

             <p> Grand total des factures</p>
         </th>

     </tr>

      @foreach (var item in Model) {
          <tr>
               <td>
                  @Model.Sum(i => i.TotalFact)
              </td>
          </tr>
      }

 </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you do not need to go over each item in the model, you are already doing sum.

```
@model IEnumerable<Tp1WebStore3.Models.Facture>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Stats";
 }

 <h2>Stats</h2>

 <p>
     Nombre de factures: @Model.Count()  
 </p>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>

             <p> Grand total des factures</p>
         </th>

     </tr>

     <tr>
          <td>
              @Model.Sum(i => i.TotalFact)
          </td>
     </tr>

 </table>
```